# CSS grid-template-areas no auto column span

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new using CSS grids and watched a few videos about it and in all of them I saw the property `grid-template-areas` which seems to be cool because you just define the same name to span columns or rows for the grid item, but it hasn't worked for me, this is my html:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "adds content";
  grid-template-rows: 3em auto;
  grid-template-columns: 20em 1fr;
}

.top-menu {
  grid-area: "header";
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #B6B0A9;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Hi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Lo</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I just use `grid-area:"header";` the div with the class top-menu doesn't span in the two columns, that's why I had to use `grid-column:span 2;` is there something that I've missed about grid-template-areas behavior? Or this isn't the proper configuration?

Comment: Change `grid-area: "header";` to `grid-area: header;`

Comment: Ori Dori, thank you, problem solved :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's something I also struggled with when starting with grid, it's easy to overlook:

when using `grid-area` you don't use `"` to define the area. So instead of `"header"` use `header`

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "adds content";
  grid-template-rows: 3em auto;
  grid-template-columns: 20em 1fr;
}

.top-menu {
  grid-area: header;
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #B6B0A9;
}

.adds {
  grid-area: adds;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Hi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Lo</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="adds">
  Some adds
</div>
<div class="content">
  Here is some content
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.item1 {
  grid-area: myArea;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'myArea myArea . . .';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The grid-template-areas Property</h1>

<p>You can use the <em>grid-template-areas</em> property to set up a grid layout.</p>
<p>Item1, is called "myArea" and will take up the place of two columns (out of five):</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
  <div class="item9">9</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```